# Finding Windows DOS Device File Paths

Tags: python, windows, driver, nfc, ctypes

I'm way outside my depth here, but am attempting to utilize the IOCTL interface to hardware on a windows machine using `python` (via `ctypes`).  I've done quite a bit of reading, and the [call signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/calling-deviceiocontrol) asks for a file handle which can be opened via the `CreateFileA` [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) function in the windows file API.  This takes a path for the file to be opened and can be passed a "Device Name" which seems to be a "MS-DOS Device Name".

The examples given are using the `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` name which I am familiar with from using tools like DISM (windows imaging), but never really knew what they were exactly.  I'd like to use the IOCTL interface with some completely unrelated to disk hardware, specifically some NFC hardware but have absolutely **no** idea how to find out what sort of device filename I should use to target the device!  [This the reference I would use to talk to the NFC chip built into my target platform (Surface Go).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/_nfpdrivers/)

Am I way off the rails here? Is what I am trying to do the wrong approach/not possible?

Comment: 'DOS' devices are the mountpoints (namespace junctions) for NT devices and file paths (e.g. a subst.exe drive) that are made available via NT's device namespace "\??\" prefix. The object manager evaluates this prefix to the local mountpoint directory of the caller, "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<Logon ID>", which shadows the global mountpoint directory, "\Global??".  The user-mode runtime library resolves and translates Windows filepaths to NT "\??\" device paths before passing them to the kernel (e.g. "C:\" -> "\??\C:\"), and the WINAPI device prefixes "\\.\" and "\\?\" simply become "\??\".

Comment: Please define the problem more precisely in terms of the IOCTLs required, to narrow down to a device interface. With the interface known, we can obtain the device path from [`SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceinterfacedetailw).

Comment: The questions are helping direct me immensely, thanks.  After looking closer, I think I would be using the "NFP" IOCTL codes specified in the `nfpdev.h` header file in the windows driver kit, e.g. `IOCTL_NFP_SET_PAYLOAD`.  If I understand correctly, devices that implement that interface should have a "Class GUID" that is specified in that file, which I can query the information set for using [SetupDiGetClassDevsExA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsexa).  I can then send that to the API call you mentioned.  Is this on the right path?

Comment: Given the interface class GUID, call `SetupDiGetClassDevsW` and `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`, and finally `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW` to get the device path that can be passed to `CreateFileW`.